# Recover wordpress plugin after deinstallation

Tags: wordpress, plugins, recover

I am developed a wordpress plugin local on my Win10 PC with XAMPP. The Plugin was finished and i just wanted to proove the uninstall process and i made a huge mistake. I didn't make a copy from the finished plugin before i tested the uninstall method and wordpress deleted the hole folder as it should.

Do you know ANY way to recover the folder? I didn't find any files in the recycle bin.

Comment: You could try recovery software like Panda Recovery or similar, but I wouldn't get my hopes up. You should consider as a developer, to **always** keep a copy of your code in the cloud. Use github, use gitlab, use bitbucket.

Comment: thanks, i tried Recuva but it couldn't find any files. Normally i use VCS systems, but this time i didn't think it is neccessary cause i worked on the plugin on my own. I will NEVER make this mistake again... The good thing is, i can refactor my code